# Combine two lists l1 x l2 into tuples

Tags: python, list

In one line, how can I generate a list which contains the tuples of all pairs of l1 x l2.

Example:
[1,2] et ['a','b'] -> [(1,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'a'), (2,'b')]

I tried to use map() and zip() but I haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: You want the _product_ of the lists.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product
numbers = [1,2]
letters = ['a','b']
result = list(product(numbers,letters))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as this.
Below is an example of a double iteration in listcomprehension.

```
numbers = [1,2]
letters = ['a','b']
new  = [(num,letter) for num in numbers for letter in letters]
```

output

```
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension.

```
list3 = [(l1,l2) for l1 in list1 for l2 in list2]
```